# Finding two vertices given the other two vertices of a rectangle.

Tags: calculus

Rectangle ABCD has vertices of A(1,0,3) and B(2,3,4), determine the coordinates of C and D if vector |AB| does not equal vector |AD|.

I know that vector AB is [1,3,1] and vector CD is the same, and the magnitude of vector AB is the square root of 11 with vector CD being the same. What would I do from here?

Answer (score 0):

You may get nothing because the conditions can not ensure the uniqueness of vector AD

Answer (score 0):

Think about this: You can move $C$ and $D$ down perpendicular to $AB$ to whatever coordinates you want, and this will still satisfy your problem. So how can you find a unique solution?